# How to add the repeated hatches to each bar in seaborn.barplot

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, bar-chart

I want add the repeated hatch patterns over a seaborn barplot.

Of course, I checked the below Q&A, but I cannot solve my question.

[Is it possible to add hatches to each individual bar in seaborn.barplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467188/is-it-possible-to-add-hatches-to-each-individual-bar-in-seaborn-barplot)

In the above Q&A, the different patch patterns are applied to the left blue ('-') and the right blue ('+').
I want apply the same patch pattern to the same color bar; ("//") should be applied on the two blue bar, ("\\") should be applied on the two green bar, and ("|") should be applied on the two red bar.

I tried the below code, but I can not realize my ideal figure.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# Set style
sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)

# Load some sample data
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")

# Make the barplot
bar = sns.barplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", data=titanic);

hatches = cycle([ "//" , "\\\\" , "|"])

# Loop over the bars
for i,thisbar in enumerate(bar.patches):
    # Set a different hatch for each bar
    thisbar.set_hatch(hatches[i])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add hash pattern to a seaborn bar plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42185000/add-hash-pattern-to-a-seaborn-bar-plot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sns.barplot` returns the matplotlib `ax` on which the bar plot has been created. (Giving the return value a very different name can be confusing when searching the seaborn and matplotlib documentation for how to make adjustments.)

`ax.patches` indeed contains all the bars. First come all bars of First Class, then all bars of Second Class, then those of Third class.  This grouping can be found in `ax.containers` which has 3 containers: one for each group of bars.  Iterating through these containers helps to hatch each group individually.  Later, the legend needs to be created again to also show the hatching.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid", color_codes=True)
titanic = sns.load_dataset("titanic")
ax = sns.barplot(x="sex", y="survived", hue="class", data=titanic)

hatches = ["//", "\\\\", "|"]
# Loop over the bars
for bars, hatch in zip(ax.containers, hatches):
    # Set a different hatch for each group of bars
    for bar in bars:
        bar.set_hatch(hatch)
# create the legend again to show the new hatching
ax.legend(title='Class')
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn barplot with hatchings]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. However, I got the error message "NameError: name 'handles' is not defined."
matplotlib ver 3.0.3 and seaborn 0.9.0 are used.

Comment: I deeply appreciated your kind support! I did reproduce the ideal figure.

Comment: Thank you for checking out the code.  The `handles` were used in my first tests, but weren't needed, and apparently I only removed them partially.  The new code should be correct.

Comment: Adding a comment to save others time, the order of hatches is reversed by the way ax.containers loops through. Quick fix is to reverse your order of hatches as `hatches = ["//", "\\\\", "|"][::-1]` in example